# How can I unwedge the end when the portal didn't spawn after killing the dragon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Our* server world has glitched out. The ender dragon is dead, but the end portal, the far portal, and the egg didn't spawn and the dragon's (full) HP bar still shows.

How can I unwedge the end? There's been a lot of construction already (before the dragon was ever killed) and I would rather not reset the map.

<sup>* Yes, I have console access.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the boss bar is still showing, are you sure the ender dragon is dead?

Try /kill @e[type=ender_dragon]

If this doesn't work, you could do /summon ender_dragon and then do the /kill command to attempt a restart of the end.

If all else fails, you could reset the specific end world file instead of the whole world file,

Comment: It was killed; but there was another ender dragon in end.

Answer (score -1):

Something may be lagging your server. If a server is lagging it will allow you to move around and damage mobs, but nothing else can occur until the lag is fixed (the server cannot communicate with the client). If not, then I don't know - do what the other answer said.

Check for world corruption too.